# Postman pre request script, How write pre request script to get value from csv file to store in variable and use on xml body?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to write pre request script to get value from csv file to store in variable and use on xml body, but I don't know where to start.

Postman Xml body that I will get a value csv file to assign a value on FirstName_Variable , LastName_Variable , Country_Variable

```
<FirstName>FirstName_Variable</FirstName>
<LastName>LastName_Variable</LastName>
<Country>Country_Variable</Country>
<Product>Loan</Product>
```

My Csv File

| FirstName | LastName | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Antname | Lnant | Japan |
| Birdname | Lnbird | Japan |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: Set variable in Body tab, make sure name of varibale is same name of table in csv file.

[image]

[image]

**Step 2**: Run by Runner function of Postman. (bottom left of Postman UI)

[image]

**Step 3** (optional): Check request body in console tab.

[image]